# What purpose does 对 serve in the sentence 因为对 汉字 感兴趣

Tags: grammar

What purpose does 对 serve in the sentence 因为对 汉字 感兴趣:yīn​wèi duì hàn​zì gǎn​xìng​qù , the meaning in English is "As he was interested in studying Chinese characters". If I take a literal interpretation of 对 in this sentence, then it would mean right. but it must serve a different purpose for this sentence(like emphasis), what is that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context, 对 can act as a preposition including 'in; on; at; to/ toward; for"

**对** 汉字 感兴趣 = interest **in** Chinese Characters

**对** 你 失望 = disappointed **on** you

**对** 你 发火 = angry **at** you

**对** 人 无礼 = rude **to** people

**对** 事件 作出解释 = explain **for** the event

Answer (score 2):

对 services as a preposition - "for; towards".

因为 **对** 汉字 感兴趣 = Because of/Due to affection **for** Chinese lettering... = because of interest **towards** Chinese lettering... = because of interested in (the) Chinese lettering...